# Python - Data structure of csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am studying about TFIDF. I have used **tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform**. It return a csr_matrix, but I can not understand what structure of the result.

- Data input:

> documents = ( "The sky is blue", "The sun is bright", "The sun in the
> sky is bright", "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun" )

- Statement:

> ```
> tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
> tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
> print(tfidf_matrix)
> ```

- The result:

> (0, 9)    0.34399327143
> (0, 7)  0.519713848879
> (0, 4)  0.420753151645
> (0, 0)    0.659191117868
> (1, 9)  0.426858009784
> (1, 4)  0.522108621994
> (1, 8)  0.522108621994
> (1, 1)  0.522108621994
> (2, 9)  0.526261040111
> (2, 7)  0.397544332095
> (2, 4)  0.32184639876
> (2, 8)  0.32184639876
> (2, 1)    0.32184639876
> (2, 3)  0.504234576856
> (3, 9)  0.390963088213
> (3, 8)    0.47820398015
> (3, 1)  0.239101990075
> (3, 10) 0.374599471224
> (3, 2)  0.374599471224
> (3, 5)  0.374599471224
> (3, 6)  0.374599471224

**tfidf_matrix** is a csr_matrix. So I find on this, but there are no structure as same as the result: [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)

What structure of value as (0, 9) 0.34399327143 ?

Comment: This looks like a matrix that collects some sort of statistic about the sentences in your list (4 of them) and unique words (11?).  For example there are 4 matrix terms for the first row, and 4 words.  `tfidt_matrix.A` should display this in a conventional matrix form.

Comment: @hpaulj: Can you help me to write down the matrix for more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the vectorize I can recreate the matrix, more or less, with this sequence of operations:

```
In [703]: documents = ( "The sky is blue", "The sun is bright", "The sun in the sky is bright", "We can see the shining sun the bright sun" )
```

get a list of lists of the words (all lower case):

```
In [704]: alist = [l.lower().split() for l in documents]
```

get a sorted list of the words (unique):

```
In [705]: aset = set()
In [706]: [aset.update(l) for l in alist]
Out[706]: [None, None, None, None]
In [707]: unq = sorted(list(aset))
In [708]: unq
Out[708]: 
['blue',
 'bright',
 'can',
 'in',
 'is',
 'see',
 'shining',
 'sky',
 'sun',
 'the',
 'we']
```

Go through the `alist` and collect word counts.  `rows` will be the sentence number, `cols` will be the unique word index

```
In [709]: rows, cols, data = [],[],[]
In [710]: for i,row in enumerate(alist):
     ...:     for c in row:
     ...:         rows.append(i)
     ...:         cols.append(unq.index(c))
     ...:         data.append(1)
     ...:
```

Make a sparse matrix from this data:

```
In [711]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data,(rows,cols)))
In [712]: M
Out[712]: 
<4x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 21 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [713]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 4)    1
  (0, 7)    1
  (0, 9)    1
  (1, 1)    1
  ....
  (3, 9)    2
  (3, 10)   1
In [714]: M.A        # viewed as 2d array
Out[714]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Since this is using `sklearn`, I can reproduce your matrix with:

```
In [717]: from sklearn import feature_extraction
In [718]: tf = feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer()
In [719]: tfM = tf.fit_transform(documents)
In [720]: tfM
Out[720]: 
<4x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 21 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [721]: print(tfM)
  (0, 9)    0.34399327143
  (0, 7)    0.519713848879
  (0, 4)    0.420753151645
  ....
  (3, 5)    0.374599471224
  (3, 6)    0.374599471224
In [722]: tfM.A
Out[722]: 
array([[ 0.65919112,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.42075315,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.51971385,  0.        ,  0.34399327,
         0.        ],....
       [ 0.        ,  0.23910199,  0.37459947,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.37459947,  0.37459947,  0.        ,  0.47820398,  0.39096309,
         0.37459947]])
```

The actual data is stored as 3 attribute arrays:

```
In [723]: tfM.indices
Out[723]: 
array([ 9,  7,  4,  0,  9,  4,  8,  1,  9,  7,  4,  8,  1,  3,  9,  8,  1,
       10,  2,  5,  6], dtype=int32)
In [724]: tfM.data
Out[724]: 
array([ 0.34399327,  0.51971385,  0.42075315,  0.65919112,  0.42685801,
       ...
        0.37459947])
In [725]: tfM.indptr
Out[725]: array([ 0,  4,  8, 14, 21], dtype=int32)
```

The `indices` values for individual rows tell us which words occur in that sentence:

```
In [726]: np.array(unq)[M[0,].indices]
Out[726]: 
array(['blue', 'is', 'sky', 'the'],
      dtype='<U7')
In [727]: np.array(unq)[M[3,].indices]
Out[727]: 
array(['bright', 'can', 'see', 'shining', 'sun', 'the', 'we'],
      dtype='<U7')
```

Comment: Thank you, very detail and helpful

Answer (score 3):

What you see is just the **string-representation** used when calling `print(my_csr_mat)`. It lists (in your case) all **nonzeros** within your matrix. (Maybe there will be a truncated output for a huge number of nonzeros).

As this is a sparse-matrix, it has 2 dimensions.

```
(0, 9) 0.34399327143
```

means: matrix-element @ position [0,9] is 0.34399327143.

Small demo:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

matrix_dense = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
zero_out = np.random.choice((0,1), size=(4,5), p=(0.7, 0.3))
matrix_dense_mod = matrix_dense * zero_out

print(matrix_dense_mod)

sparse_mat = csr_matrix(matrix_dense_mod)

print(sparse_mat)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  0  2  0  4]
 [ 0  6  0  8  0]
 [ 0 11  0 13 14]
 [15  0  0 18 19]]
  (0, 2)        2
  (0, 4)        4
  (1, 1)        6
  (1, 3)        8
  (2, 1)        11
  (2, 3)        13
  (2, 4)        14
  (3, 0)        15
  (3, 3)        18
  (3, 4)        19
```

I'm not sure what you mean by `So I find on this, but there are no structure as same as the result`, but beware: **most examples in scipy.sparse docs have a my_mat.toarray() in the print-call which means it's building a dense array from the sparse matrix which has a different string-representation style**.