# How can I change my index vector into sparse feature vector that can be used in sklearn?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am doing a News recommendation system and I need to build a table for users and news they read. my raw data just like this :

```
001436800277225 [12,456,157]
009092130698762 [248]
010003000431538 [361,521,83]
010156461231357 [173,67,244]
010216216021063 [203,97]
010720006581483 [86]
011199797794333 [142,12,86,411,201]
011337201765123 [123,41]
011414545455156 [62,45,621,435]
011425002581540 [341,214,286]
```

the first column is `userID`, the second column is the `newsID`.`newsID` is a index column, for example, after transformation, `[12,456,157]` in the first row means that this user has read the 12th, 456th and 157th news (in sparse vector, the 12th column, 456th column and 157th column are `1`, while other columns have value `0`). And I want to change these data into a sparse vector format that can be used as input vector in Kmeans or DBscan algorithm  of `sklearn`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to construct the sparse matrix explicitly.  I often find it easier to build the matrix in [COO matrix format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) and then cast to [CSR format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

input_data = [
    ("001436800277225", [12,456,157]),
    ("009092130698762", [248]),
    ("010003000431538", [361,521,83]),
    ("010156461231357", [173,67,244])    
]

NUMBER_MOVIES = 1000 # maximum index of the movies in the data
NUMBER_USERS = len(input_data) # number of users in the model

# you'll probably want to have a way to lookup the index for a given user id.
user_row_map = {}
user_row_index = 0

# structures for coo format
I,J,data = [],[],[]
for user, movies in input_data:

    if user not in user_row_map:
        user_row_map[user] = user_row_index
        user_row_index+=1

    for movie in movies:
        I.append(user_row_map[user])
        J.append(movie)
        data.append(1)  # number of times users watched the movie

# create the matrix in COO format; then cast it to CSR which is much easier to use
feature_matrix = coo_matrix((data, (I,J)), shape=(NUMBER_USERS, NUMBER_MOVIES)).tocsr()
```

Comment: `csr_matrix` accepts the `coo` style of inputs.  In practice though it does what you do - make a `coo` and then convert.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn.preprocessing`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.newsID), columns=mlb.classes_)

   12   41   45   62   67   83   86   97   123  142 ...   244  248  286  341  361  411  435  456  521  621
0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 ...     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 ...     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0 ...     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
3    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0 ...     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0 ...     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0 ...     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1 ...     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
7    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0 ...     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
8    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0 ...     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
9    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 ...     0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a good way to do it. But my data is high-dimensional, like about 800000*92000, and the  number of 1 in each row just have less than 10 columns, while the other 90000+columns are 0.  I feel that this solution may waste lots of resource, doesn't it ?

Comment: `sklearn` might have a processor that creates a sparse matrix, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678491/python-data-structure-of-csr-matrix.  Pandas sparse format is different from the `scipy` one.